# Rad file generated by eclipse

Tags: rad

What is the use of this file in a RAD : org.eclipse.wst.common.component. The contents are like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
    <wb-module deploy-name="WebProj">
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/src/java"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/test"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/test/conf"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/src/conf"/>
        <property name="java-output-path" value="src/java"/>
    </wb-module>
</project-modules>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In RAD,the builds are integrated with Eclipse and so there are all these oddball files that you may not recognize if you are not used to dealing with RAD/Websphere.  It looks like this one configures the context root and what source directories to build out for the web app.  In RAD, you're not supposed to edit these files directly--there is an (often obscure) UI for everything.  There is also an equally obscure way to script everything in each UI, too.